# Can a real sequence approach/converge to an imaginary number? How it would look like?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, complex-numbers

I was working on this proposition:

> If the real sequence $\{a_n^2\}$ converges, then the sequence $\{a_n\}$ also converges.

So, we can use the multiplicative property of convergence/limit:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n^2= A \\
\left(\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n \right)^2= A \\
\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n= \sqrt{A}
$$
But what if $A$ is negative? If $A$ is negative, then the the last line says that the real sequence $\{a_n\}$ approaches a complex number, but that we know is not possible and hence the proposition doesn’t hold true if the sequence $\{a_n^2\}$ approaches a negative number. But I’m curious of what it actually means if we have something like this :
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = x +iy 
$$ (where $x$ and $y$ are fixed real numbers). What it’s picture gonna look like, I know $\{a_n\}$ is not going to infinity, I know it’s not oscillating either, what it is doing pictorially if it is approaching a complex number?

Comment: Real numbers **are** complex numbers, with imaginary part $0$. Just to be pedantic.

Comment: The proposition is false. Consider $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: The title does not reflect the question. To answer the question in the title, the answer is *no* because the real line is a closed subset of the complex plane.

Comment: A real sequence cannot converge to a non-real number because the real numbers are a *closed* subset of $\Bbb C$

Answer (score 5):

You want the sequence to converge to $x + iy$ where $y \neq 0$.  Set $\epsilon = \frac{|y|}{2}$.  No real number can be within $\epsilon$ of $x + iy$ so what you want is not possible.